# how sparse array differs from a hashmap in java

Tags: java, android, hashmap, sparse-array

In my **Android** application I have used **Hash maps** in many situations. And I was asked to use **sparse arrays** by concerning the performance of the application. So,  how **sparse array** differs from a **hashmap** in **java** and what are the advantages of **sparse array over hashmap** . Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I beleive the description of sparse array clearly mentions the difference:

> It is intended to be more memory efficient than using a HashMap to map
>   Integers to Objects, both because **it avoids auto-boxing keys and its
>   data structure doesn't rely on an extra entry object for each mapping**.

For further reading: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html